# Print Object as Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this state

```
const [value, setValue] = useState([]) // init with empty array
```

Which I set like this

```
  async function createSalesOrder () {
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/')
      setValue([...value, JSON.stringify(res.data)])
      return (res)
    }
```

Here the response is a Object but I convert it to a string because else I can't set the state, react doesnt allow me use a object

The object which gets returned looks like this

```
response.data.salesOrderId
response.data.quantity
```

And I want to print the data in a table

```
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>res.data.salesOrderId</td>
                <td>res.data.quantity</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

How can I achieve this? React doesn't allow me to use JSON.parse in the return block

Comment: Add `{}` outside your value, example: `<td>{res.data.salesOrderId}</td>`

Comment: Why would you stringify the API data...? If axios doesn't already do it for you, you'd *parse* it, but certainly not stringify it. Anyway, to display an array as table you use something like `{value.map(row => <tr key={row.salesOrderId}><td>row.salesOrderId</td><td>row.quantity</td></tr>)}` in the `<tbody>`.

Comment: If I replace JSON.stringify with JSON.parse i get the following error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: That may very well be, but if parsing doesn't work, don't just replace it with stringify and hope for the best... what exactly does localhost:5000 send back, and in which format?

Comment: It returns an object

Comment: Duh. In JSON format I assume? Did you try `setValue([...value, res.data])`?

Comment: I get the following error if I try that: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {salesOrderId}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.